# Javascript not executing inside shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-component, shadow-dom, html5-template

I am working on an application where I've to load other html webpages to current page. Other webpages are independent applications. I am trying to load webpage in shadow DOM. For that I've used below code, where it will try to import test-template.html in shadowRoot. Here I am not using template tag, because I've to render template dynamically (Using ajax).

```
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="button" onclick="loadTemplate()" value="Load template">
     <div id="template-holder"></div>
     <script>
     function loadTemplate() {
      var templateUrl = "test-template.html",
      templateReceivedCallback = function(response) {
         var div = document.getElementById('template-holder'),
            shadowRoot = div.attachShadow({
                mode: 'open'
            });
        shadowRoot.innerHTML = response;
      };
     $.get(templateUrl, templateReceivedCallback);
     }
  </script>
 </body>
```

And test-template.html will look like this:

```
  <div>Hello from template</div>

 <script>
     alert("this text is from script inside of template")
 </script>
```

I am able to load the mentioned test-template.html in my current page, but javascript inside of test-template.html is not executing. Is there any way to make the script run ? If yes, please share the running example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make the `<script>` active, you should first insert the loaded file in a `<template>` element.
Then use the `importNode()` method that will clone the `content` of the template and execute the scripts inside.

Instead of:

```
shadowRoot.innerHTML = response;
```

Do:

```
var template = document.createElement( 'template' )
template.innerHTML = response 
shadowRoot.appendChild( document.importNode( template.content, true ) )
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, and upvoted  your answer :p

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore... I get no console.log print or alert.  class ViewMedia extends HTMLElement {
   constructor() {
      super();
      const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
     // initElem(shadow, this.getAttribute('data-value'));
     var template = document.createElement( 'template' );
     template.innerHTML = '<script>alert("hello"); console.log("hello from tpl");</script>';
     shadow.appendChild( document.importNode( template.content, true ) ); 
     console.log(shadow);
    return;

Comment: @mike you should post another question for it's not the same problem