# Insert multiple instances of a same widget into a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

I have a widget which renders a bar chart(HTML/CSS/JavaScript), after point to a particular datasource/API. There is a configuration parameter to change the datasource/API, So I can have multiple instances of the same widget.

Is it possible to do above with the use of shadow-dom? I tried following but noticed widget is unable to select the correct div-element to do the rendering part.

```
        var host = document.querySelector("#" + gadgetContainer.getAttribute("data-grid-id"));
        var root = host.createShadowRoot();

        var template = document.createElement('template');
        template.innerHTML = gadgetContainer.outerHTML; 
        root.appendChild(document.importNode(template.content, true));
```

Following is the JavaScript logic which do the widget rendering, I have removed dataset and the config for clarity.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    //dataset used to plot charts
    var dataTable = {}, //REMOVED
        width = document.querySelector('*::shadow #bar').offsetWidth,
        height = 270,   //canvas height
        config = {}; //REMOVED
    widget.renderer.setWidgetName("bar-chart", "BAR CHART");

    chartLib.plot("*::shadow #bar",config, dataTable);
}());
```

Following is the simple HTML div, all required stylesheets and scripts are there in this page.

```
<div id="bar" class="bar"></div>
```

Comment: @Supersharp rendering of multiple instances of the same widget.

Comment: @Supersharp I have updated the Question with more code. Im only using shadow-dom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal example of a reuse of a template to create 2 instances of the same widget with Shadow DOM:

```js
var template = document.querySelector( 'template' )

target1.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
       .appendChild( template.content.cloneNode( true ) )
       
target2.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
       .appendChild( template.content.cloneNode( true ) )
```

```html
<template>
  <style>
    :host { display: inline-block; width:100px; height:50px ; border: 1px solid gray; }
    header { color: blue; font-size:15px; font-weight: bold; }
    section { color: gray; font-size:12px ; }
  </style>
  <header>
     Widget <slot name="number"></slot>
  </header>
  <section>
     Content
  </section>
</template>

<div id="target1"><span slot="number">1</span></div>

<div id="target2"><span slot="number">2</span></div>
```

Note that you should use Shadow DOM "v1", with `attachShadow()` instead of `createShadowRoot()` as it's the standard specification that will be implemented on browsers other that Chrome. The old version will be deprecated in the future.

Use `<slot>` to get the content of the light DOM and insert it in the Shadow DOM.

Comment: Assume I have a template like this, https://jsfiddle.net/4qu6jks3/ where I have to execute a script tag. Tried this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40736326/javascript-not-executing-inside-shadow-dom with no luck.

Comment: @udarakr The best way is to define a custom element: jsfiddle.net/woekreuc/2. Or else you would have to update the shadow dom' content from the outside (or update the template's clone before insertion in the shadow dom)